# Why Google Chrome increase the memory usage on each page reload?

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks

When I open the Google Chrome task manager I can see the amount of memory use for each task/tab.

Each time I load a page in a tab I can see how the amount of memory is increased. I've done it  with facebook.com, It starts in 80MB, after 25 reloads task manager says the amount of memory used is 546MB!!

Is that normal? Is it a bug which I should report to Google?

I've discovered it after notice my Google Chrome is getting slow.

My version of Chrome is Versión 33.0.1750.117

[image]

Comment: I've had a [discussion](http://www.daniweb.com/community-center/daniweb-community-feedback/threads/473863/memory-leak-in-daniweb-chrome#post2069632) about another recent memory leak issue, with the same version of Chrome. This seems to be a wide-spread problem. It must be an internal bug with Chrome's new javascript engine (V8) that causes significant leaks.

Comment: I've already reported it to Google but no answer by now.

Comment: 03/13/2015 with Chrome 41.0 and still the same bug, that is really annoying when building large web apps. Could you please check again and unmark the answer as accepted so people keep providing solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely it's a Google Chrome issue, it has been fixed in the latest version (33.0.1750.152).

Unfortunately Google has not confirmed me this issue, but it's working now.

Comment: I am using Version 37.0.2062.120 m and still getting this issue!!! can it be due to my app??

Comment: Same here on Mac OS X - Chrome 39.0.2171.36 beta (64-bit)

Comment: Getting the same issue on Mac OS X - Chrome 45.0.2454.85

Answer (score 2):

It's not normal and I've tested it myself in a couple of sites and it seems like a bug and we should report it.

Comment: I've reported it but Google doesn't answer me.

Answer (score 2):

Although the Chrome team has fixed a few memory leaks, it seems like they still have not fixed all of them ([see here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=270000)). In my particular case, however, I was able to solve the problem with the following JavaScript snippet:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
});
```

Hope this helps someone. I have limited it to Chrome with browser sniffing:

```
var isChrome = window.chrome && /Google/.test(navigator.vendor) && !/OPR|Edge/.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) with both Chrome and Firefox. I solved the problem by switching back to the 32-bit kernel.

[OS X: Starting up with the 32-bit or 64-bit kernel](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3773)