# Node.js web app chrome memory usage increasing after every reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I've build a web app using node.js to display information to our users. However I'm seeing an unhealthy increase in the memory usage every time the page is refreshed (`location.reload()`).

on first load it's 425MB,
787MB on the 2nd,
1075MB on the 3rd,
1350mb on the 4th etc... I've seen it climb to 5/6GBs

The only way to fix this is to close the tab and start from a new tab.

I can't see any increase while the page is sat idle or if you navigate round the page. It's like chrome is keeping the old page every time the page is reloaded. I have tried turning caching off from the dev tools but that didn't do anything. I've tried looking at the memory dev tools but I can't really make heads or tails of it.

is there a solution to this?

Comment: It would seem like a memory leak on the frontend. Have you tried using another browser just to confirm if it´s Chrome or your webapp?

Comment: @user2895707 This appears to only happen in Chrome just tested with Edge and it's fine memory usage doesn't increase

Comment: @user2895707 I can confirm however that the same memory increase is happening in Firefox

Comment: try the solution I posted and let me know if it worked.

Comment: I've got the same issue with a large Angular app, when the devtools are open the reloading keeps bloating the memory. I've tried the unload trick but it hasn't worked for me. I'm wondering if it's something to do with the the way ng serve communicates with the page using a websocket and that's not being cleaned up, not sure though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with Google Chrome since at least [2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015470/why-google-chrome-increase-the-memory-usage-on-each-page-reload)

You can use this workaround made in the linked 2016 question:

```js
window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
});
```

And add the following metatags to limit the browser from caching the site.

```html
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> 
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'> 
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Comment: Thank you this has worked for both firefox and Chrome. I had see the 2016 answer but since it was such an old bug I though it would have been fixed. Also when trying to add it to my code it didn't work first but I put it in the wrong place i just had to add it as the first thing in the .js file